# How do I include .dll file in executable using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, numpy, dll, pyinstaller

I want to generate a single executable file from my python script.
For this I use pyinstaller. I had issues with mkl libraries because I use numpy in the script.

I used this [hook](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1881) so solve the issue, it worked fine. But it does not work if I copy the single executable file to another directory and execute it. I guess I have to copy the hook also. But I just want to have one single file that I can use at other computers without copying `.dll's` or the hook.

I also changed the `.spec` file as described [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html) and added the necessary files to the `binaries`-variable. That also works as long as the `.dll's` are in the provided directory for the `binaries`-variable , but that won't work when I use the executable on a computer that doesn't have these `.dll's`.

I tried using the `--hidden-import= FILENAME` option. This also solves the issue, but just when the `.dll's` are provided somewhere.

What I'm looking for is a possibility to bundle the `.dll's` into the single executable file so that I have one file that works independently.

Comment: you can add the `dll` directory to the `PATH` evironment variable and it should work fine

Comment: Ok, but this would not work at another machine, right? Because on another computer this path is not valid and the dll might not be existent

Answer (score 16):

When I faced problem described here
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/443
my workaround was

`pyinstaller -F --add-data vcruntime140.dll;. myscript.py`

`-F` - collect into one **.exe* file

`.` - Destination path of dll in exe file

from docs
http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

Add the current project folder to Path, then Create EXE using following command:

```
pyinstaller --add-binary AutoItX3_x64.dll;. program_name.py
```

Create folder `\dist\program_name\autoit\lib` in tge current project folder, and paste `AutoItX3_x64.dll` in it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modified version of Ilya's answer.

`pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary ".venv/Lib/site-packages/example_package/example.dll;." myscript.py`

It wasn't clear to me when first stumbling into this issue that you must tell PyInstaller exactly where to find the given file (either via relative or absolute path) if it is not already on your `PATH`.

I have more discussion on how I found exactly which DLL was missing in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69981523/1437625) to a similar question.

I much prefer this solution to manually copying DLLs into the export directory, since single EXE is better for distributing utilities to non-programmers.

Answer (score 1):

As the selected answer didn't work for the case of using **libportaudio64bit.dll**, I put my working solution here.

For me, the working solution is to add **_sounddevice_data** folder where the .exe file is located then making a **portaudio-binaries** folder in it and finally putting **libportaudio64bit.dll** in the recently created folder.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This really helped me, so thank you very much :). One other thing you might want to add to your answer is that you mustn't use the `--onefile` flag. :)

Comment: @ed-ward What happens with the --onefile flag?  Doesn't that help make it more portable by putting everything into the single executable?